# Wat is the Polars equivalent of Pandas idxmin in a groupby aggregate?

Tags: group-by, python-polars

I'm looking for a Polars equivalent of Pandas idxmin in a group_by agg operation

With Polars and this example dataframe:

```py
    import polars as pl

    dct = {
        "a": [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        "b": [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5],
        "c": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
        "d": [0.18418279, 0.67394382, 0.80951643, 0.10115085, 0.03998497, 0.17771175, 0.28428486,     0.24553192, 0.31388881, 0.07525366, 0.28622033, 0.61240989]
    }

    df = pl.DataFrame(dct)
    df

    a   b   c   d
    i64 i64 i64 f64
    0   0   0   0.184183
    0   0   1   0.673944
    0   1   2   0.809516
    0   1   3   0.101151
    1   2   4   0.039985
    1   2   5   0.177712
    1   3   6   0.284285
    1   3   7   0.245532
    2   4   8   0.313889
    2   4   9   0.075254
    2   5   10  0.28622
    2   5   11  0.61241
```

and group_by operation:

```py
    df.group_by(["a", "b"], maintain_order=True).agg(pl.col('d').min())

    shape: (6, 3)
    a   b   d
    i64 i64 f64
    0   0   0.184183
    0   1   0.101151
    1   2   0.039985
    1   3   0.245532
    2   4   0.075254
    2   5   0.28622
```

I need the values in column c of the original dataframe that correspond to the aggregated values in colomn d.

In Pandas I can get that result with:

```py
    import pandas as pd
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(dct)
    df2.iloc[df2.groupby(["a", "b"]).agg({"d": "idxmin"}).d]
        a   b   c   d
    0   0   0   0   0.184183
    3   0   1   3   0.101151
    4   1   2   4   0.039985
    7   1   3   7   0.245532
    9   2   4   9   0.075254
    10  2   5   10  0.286220
```

I've not found an equivalent function for idxmin in Polars. There is arg_min, but it does not give the desired result as can be seen in this output:

```py
    df.group_by(["a", "b"], maintain_order=True).agg(pl.col('d').arg_min())

    shape: (6, 3)
    a   b   d
    i64 i64 u32
    0   0   0
    0   1   1
    1   2   0
    1   3   1
    2   4   1
    2   5   0
```

The actual dataframe has several million rows and takes a long time (minutes) in Pandas to compute.
How can I achieve the same result in Polars efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Expr.get` to get from a column by index.

```py
df.group_by(["a", "b"], maintain_order=True).agg(
    c=pl.col("c").get(pl.col("d").arg_min()), d=pl.col("d").min(),
)
```

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬──────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   ┆ d        │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---      │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ f64      │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪══════════╡
│ 0   ┆ 0   ┆ 0   ┆ 0.184183 │
│ 0   ┆ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ 0.101151 │
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 4   ┆ 0.039985 │
│ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ 7   ┆ 0.245532 │
│ 2   ┆ 4   ┆ 9   ┆ 0.075254 │
│ 2   ┆ 5   ┆ 10  ┆ 0.28622  │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴──────────┘
```

Comment: Even more efficient and concise. Runs at roughly ~0.8s compared to 89sec Pandas for my 3M row dataframe. Polars is truly powerfull. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```py
df.with_row_count().group_by("a", "b", maintain_order=True).agg(
    pl.col("d").min(),
    pl.col("row_nr").filter(pl.col("d") == pl.col("d").min()).first()
)
```

which gives

```
shape: (6, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬──────────┬────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ d        ┆ row_nr │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---      ┆ ---    │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ f64      ┆ u32    │
╞═════╪═════╪══════════╪════════╡
│ 0   ┆ 0   ┆ 0.184183 ┆ 0      │
│ 0   ┆ 1   ┆ 0.101151 ┆ 3      │
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 0.039985 ┆ 4      │
│ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ 0.245532 ┆ 7      │
│ 2   ┆ 4   ┆ 0.075254 ┆ 9      │
│ 2   ┆ 5   ┆ 0.28622  ┆ 10     │
└─────┴─────┴──────────┴────────┘
```

Comment: Excellent, works fine and efficient (~1.5 sec) on the actual 3M row dataframe. Many thanks!

Comment: happy to help - just out of interest, how long was it with the pandas code?

Comment: The Pandas version was 89 sec